# phonegap 1.7 notificationCallback(this function this.sendJavascript(js)) is not working

Tags: android, cordova

**For Android** i am using phonegap 1.7(cordova-1.7.0.js). i am sending push notification using urban airship.

"notificationCallback" function is not woring when i received the message. here is my code.

```
     PushNotificationPlugin.java

     package org.minimoesfuerzo.plugins;

     import org.json.JSONArray;
     import org.json.JSONException;
     import org.json.JSONObject;

     import android.util.Log;

     import com.phonegap.api.Plugin;
     import com.phonegap.api.PluginResult;
     import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult.Status;

     public class PushNotificationPlugin extends Plugin {
        final static String TAG = PushNotificationPlugin.class.getSimpleName();

    static PushNotificationPlugin instance = null;

    public static final String ACTION = "registerCallback";

    public PushNotificationPlugin() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static PushNotificationPlugin getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void sendResultBack(String msg, String payload) {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        try {
            data.put("msg", msg);
            data.put("payload", payload);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        String js = String.format("window.plugins.pushNotification.notificationCallback('%s');", data.toString());
        this.sendJavascript(js);
    }

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray data,
            String callbackId) {

        PluginResult result = null;
        if (ACTION.equals(action)) {
            result = new PluginResult(Status.NO_RESULT);
            result.setKeepCallback(false);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Invalid action: " + action + " passed");
            result = new PluginResult(Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Receiver Class

```
     package org.minimoesfuerzo.ua;

     import org.minimoesfuerzo.plugins.PushNotificationPlugin;

     import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.util.Log;

     import com.appstockholm.zoud.MainActivity;
     import com.urbanairship.UAirship;
     import com.urbanairship.push.PushManager;

     public class IntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //private static final String TAG = IntentReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String TAG = "humayoo";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received intent: " + intent.toString());
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(PushManager.ACTION_PUSH_RECEIVED)) {
            int id = intent.getIntExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);

            Log.i(TAG, "Received push notification. Alert: " + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_ALERT)
                + ". Payload: " + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_STRING_EXTRA) + ". NotificationID="+id);

            String alert = intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_ALERT);
            String extra = intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_STRING_EXTRA);

            PushNotificationPlugin plugin = PushNotificationPlugin.getInstance();
            plugin.sendResultBack(alert, extra);

        } else if (action.equals(PushManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_OPENED)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "User clicked notification. Message: " + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_ALERT)
                    + ". Payload: " + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_STRING_EXTRA));

            Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            launch.setClass(UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext().startActivity(launch);
            String alert = intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_ALERT);
            String extra = intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_STRING_EXTRA);

            PushNotificationPlugin plugin = PushNotificationPlugin.getInstance();
            plugin.sendResultBack(alert, extra);

        } else if (action.equals(PushManager.ACTION_REGISTRATION_FINISHED)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration complete. APID:" + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_APID)
                    + ". Valid: " + intent.getBooleanExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_REGISTRATION_VALID, false));
        }
    }
}
```

Pushnotification.js file

```
var PushNotification = {
    registerCallback: function(successCallback, failureCallback) {
        return PhoneGap.exec(
               successCallback,           // called when signature capture is successful
               failureCallback,           // called when signature capture encounters an error
               'PushNotificationPlugin',  // Tell PhoneGap that we want to run "PushNotificationPlugin"
               'registerCallback',        // Tell the plugin the action we want to perform
               []);                       // List of arguments to the plugin
    },
    notificationCallback: function(json) {
        var data = window.JSON.parse(json);
        alert("Success: " +  data.msg);

    }
};

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin("pushNotification", PushNotification);
});
```

Comment: Just curious if you found a fix in the meantime.  I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my migration guide for plugins on 1.5+ or greater:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/04/migrating-your-phonegap-plugins-to.html

Also, did you remember to put your plugins line in plugins.xml?

Comment: 1.i put the my plugin to plugin.xml file.

Comment: 1.i put the my plugin to plugin.xml file. 

2.when i call send back result function ("sendResultBack" mention is pushnotificationplugin.java file in above post)
from urban airship receiver class, "this.sendJavascript(js)" is not working. its through null
in your post there is no mentioned about sendcallback function call